# Cast Error on passing Integer Nav Argument using SavedStateHandle in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to navigate from the first screen to a second screen and I need to provide an integer identifier to load stuff from API on the second screen.

I'm running into this error when trying to pass an Int Nav Argument.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

This is my NavHost where I use `/{recipeId}` as my placeholder on the 2nd Screen's route.

```
            NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screens.RecipesOverviewScreen.route
                ) {

                    //1st Screen
                    composable(route = Screens.RecipesOverviewScreen.route) {

                        RecipesOverviewScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                            onToggleTheme = { app.toggleLightTheme() })
                    }

                    //2nd Screen
                    composable(route = "${Screens.RecipeDetailScreen.route}/{recipeId}")
                    {
                        RecipeDetailScreen()
                    }
```

I then call `navController.navigate()` in the first screen passing in an `id` of type Int into the navigation route.

```
RecipeList(recipes = listState.recipes,
                    onClickRecipeCard = { id ->
                    
                        //insert corresponding Int id into the Nav route
                        navController.navigate(
                        route = "${Screens.RecipeDetailScreen.route}/${id}"
     
                        )
                    }
```

Inside the 2nd Screen's ViewModel I retrieve the nav argument using the SavedHandleInstance.

```
@HiltViewModel
class RecipeViewModel @Inject constructor(
   
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        //pass in the key inside get() fxn
        savedStateHandle.get<Int>(Constants.PARAM_RECIPE_ID)
                ?.let { id ->
                    //perform an API call inside init{} using nav arg id
                   getRecipe(id = id, token = token)

                    
                } ....}
```

At this point, the app is crashing and I am getting the above logcat output.

Kindly point me in the right direction on passing an Int Nav arg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you defined your 2nd screen as:

```
composable(route = "${Screens.RecipeDetailScreen.route}/{recipeId}") {
```

You didn't define any type for the `recipeId` argument. As per the [Navigate with arguments guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args):

> By default, all arguments are parsed as strings. You can specify another type by using the `arguments` parameter to set a `type`

So if you want your `recipeId` to be an `Int`, you must declare it as an [`IntType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavType.Companion#IntType()):

```
composable(
  route = "${Screens.RecipeDetailScreen.route}/{recipeId}",
  arguments = listOf(navArgument("recipeId") { type = NavType.IntType })
) {
```

This will ensure that your call to `savedStateHandle.get<Int>` actually has an `Int` to find, rather than a `String`.